How to implement SSL/TLS in cesanta mongoose embedded?
I am trying to implement SSL/TLS in my web server in an embedded system, according to mongoose tutorial I have written the following code which uses mongoose builtin TLS1.3. But I get  "TLS not enabled" error once server accept the connection. Can someone tell me what is the problem in code. I have also enabled the pre-processor variable MG_TLS=MG_TLS_BUILTIN.


static const char *s_tls_cert ="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" 
                    "ABCD\n"
                    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"; // Actual certificate created will be copied here as a string

static const char *s_tls_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"    
                    "ABCD\n"
                    "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // Actual private key created will be copied here


void fn(struct mg_connection *c, int ev, void *ev_data, void *fn_data)
{


if (ev == MG_EV_ACCEPT)
    {
      struct mg_tls_opts opts = {
     .cert = s_tls_cert,
     .certkey = s_tls_key};
     mg_tls_init(c, &opts);
   }


  if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_MSG)
    {
      struct mg_http_message *hm = (struct mg_http_message *) ev_data;
      if (mg_http_match_uri(hm, "/api/login"))
    {
      mg_http_reply(c, 200, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n", "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Welcome User</body></html>");
    }
    }
}



void task1(void)
{
  struct mg_mgr mgr;
  mg_mgr_init(&mgr);                                     
  mg_log_set(MG_LL_DEBUG);
  mg_http_listen(&mgr, "https://0.0.0.0:8443", fn, &mgr);
  for (;;)mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 1000, 1);
  mg_mgr_free(&mgr);
} 


You're using a quite old version. The ev_data argument in the event handler is long gone. I suggest to use the latest version. Take http-restful-server as an example, it starts both HTTP and HTTPS listener.
See https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/tutorials/http/http-restful-server

I was using mongoose 7.8, updating to new version solved the issue. Thanks for the answer.

Anusha, did you know we have

Detailed tutorials where we explain how to do that

https://mongoose.ws/documentation/tutorials/tls/#how-to-build
https://mongoose.ws/documentation/tutorials/http/http-server/


A Github repository with a place to ask questions https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/discussions
A detailed full working example (linked at the tutorial above) that does just what you are trying to do

https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/tutorials/http/http-restful-server



?
If you "get" "TLS not enabled" it is because, well, TLS not enabled. That means you did not do things properly.
You say that you "have also enabled the pre-processor variable MG_TLS=MG_TLS_BUILTIN", well, not "also", you MUST define that, otherwise, TLS is not enabled. And that means you have to properly build the project/example,
as explained in the tutorial linked above:
make all CFLAGS_EXTRA="-DMG_TLS=MG_TLS_BUILTIN"

if you are using make and one of our examples. Otherwise, of course you have to pass that to your compìler, the way your compiler expects that to be passed. For gcc/clang and many others:
gcc -DMG_TLS=MG_TLS_BUILTIN -o yourprog yourprog.c mongoose.c

thing you can infer by inspecting our Makefile
$(PROG): $(SOURCES) Makefile
         $(CC) $(SOURCES) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_MONGOOSE) $(CFLAGS_EXTRA) $(OUT)

And as said, we have an example that does just what you are trying to do:
# Mongoose build options. See https://mongoose.ws/documentation/#build-options
CFLAGS_MONGOOSE += -DMG_ENABLE_LINES=1 -DMG_TLS=MG_TLS_BUILTIN

Your problem with this, is not in your code, it is in how you are trying to build.
That very example just works. If you are not using make, then see how we invoke gcc/clang, be it in Windows, Linux, Mac
If you are not using one of the supported compilers, then learn how to properly pass definitions to your compiler.
